# escape() doesn't seem to work consistently?

Tags: javascript, string, browser, escaping

using javascript, I generate HTML code, for example adding an function which starts by clicking a link, like:

```
$('#myDiv').append('<a href="javascript:start(\''+TERM+'\');">click</a>');
```

So `start()` should be called if somebody hits the link (click).
`TERM` could contain a single word, like `world` or `moody's`, the generated HTML code would look like:

```
<a href="javascript:start('world');">click</a>
```

OR

```
<a href="javascript:start('moody's');">click</a>
```

As you can see, the 2nd example will not work. So i decided to "escape" the `TERM`, like so:

```
$('#myDiv').append('<a href="javascript:start(\''+escape(TERM)+'\');">click</a>');
```

Looking at the HTML source-code using firebug, is see, that the following code was generated:

```
<a href="javascript:start('moody%27s');">click</a>
```

Thats works fine, until  I really click the link - so the browser (here firefox) seams to interpret the `%27` and tries to fire `start('moody's');`

Is there a way to escape the term persistent without interpreting the `%27` until the term is handled in JS? Is there an other solution instead of using regular expressions to change `'` to `\'`?

Comment: What's wrong with `.replace`?

Comment: what about using an event on the generated HTML, something like [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (I've seen that you didn't tag your question with jquery but that's just a suggestion :))

Comment: @Dave Newton there is nothig wrong with `.replace` - thats the only workaround i know, but maybe sombody knows an better solution, like "changing" the TERM "by hand" ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

escape() is used for url-encoding stuff, not for making it possible to put in a string literal. Your code is seriously flawed for several reasons.

If you want an onclick event, use an onclick event. Do not try to "inject" javascript code with your markup. If you have the "string" in a variable, you should never need to substitute anything in it unless you are generating urls or other restricted terms.

```
var element = $('<span>click</span>');
element.bind('click', function () { start(TERM); });
$('#myDiv').append(element);
```

If you don't know what this does, then go back to basic and learn what events and function references in javascript means.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to generate inline JavaScript. That way lies too much pain and maintenance hell. (If you were to go down that route, then you would escape characters in JavaScript strings with `\`).

Use standard event binding routines instead.

Assuming that `$` is jQuery, and not one of the many other libraries that use that unhelpful variable name:

```
$('#myDiv').append(
    $('<a>').append("click").attr('href', 'A sensible fallback').click(function (e) {
        alert(TERM); // Because I don't have the function you were calling
        e.preventDefault();
   })
);
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/TudEw/

Comment: Agreed, but the problem is the same.

Comment: No it's not, because you can say `start(TERM);` (leave out the single quotes) which is bound to the value at that time.

Comment: @Dave Newton — No, it isn't. The problem is nested string quoting when trying to use JavaScript to generate HTML with embedded JavaScript. By removing the "embedded JavaScript" part of it, that problem goes away.

Comment: @Quentin Ah, yeah, duh; the quotes in your original through me off--sorry!

Comment: I missed that it was a variable on my first read though, I fixed that.

Comment: I hate it when I have to vote up comments that make me look dumb. But I'm getting used to it.

Comment: I see, that this answer has 3 upvotes, while  the answer from @jishi does not have one upvote. Is there e reason, why? Is that solution best practice?

Answer (score 0):

That `escape()` function is for escaping url's for passing over a network, not strings.  I don't know that there's a built-in function to escape strings for JavaScript, but you can try this one I found online: http://www.willstrohl.com/Blog/EntryId/67/HOW-TO-Escape-Single-Quotes-for-JavaScript-Strings.

Usage:  `EscapeSingleQuotes(strString)`

**Edit:** Just noticed your note about regular expressions.  This solution *does* use regular expressions, but I think there's nothing wrong with that :-)